# Google Translation API v2 Jar file

Tags: java, jar, google-translate, google-translation-api

I'm trying to use Google Translation API v2 for my project.

Google Translation API Link :: https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/

I wanted to try the free trail first. I set up the account and configured the billing information and downloaded the JSON file as said in the guide.

Now, to use the API, I need the jar file of google translate api. There seems to be no link for a jar file in the guide or documentation. How can I get the jar file?

Answer (score 0):

You are right, the [Quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/quickstart) does not mention a jar, as it does not cover app development; it only covers how to make an API call using the "curl" command.

You may find an Java app development [example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/master/translate/) on github.